# WFS returns 2 records, QGIS shows only one

Tags: qgis, wfs

When I show a WFS layer (published by GeoServer) in QGIS, I'm missing one of the two records.

What I do:

1. Select the WFS layer
2. Setup a query (properties -> query-builder) (eg `postalcode = '1234'`)
3. Then hit 'test' in the query builder -> "The WHERE clause returned 2 rows"
4. Then I look at the layer and i'm missing one of two polygons
5. Also, the attribute table contains only one row.

So, there is a mechanism with which QGIS merges records. In my case the records are, besides 2 columns (geo and one other), completely similar.
There is no primary key (it is a db-view in PostgreSQL) so, maybe, QGIS just takes the first column?

Is there a setting in QGIS to make sure *every* record is returned?

Comment: I believe that from features with the same fid only one is kept. Otherwise queries made by view extent would lead to loads of duplicates.

Comment: are the Polygons distinct?

Comment: @user30184 Indeed they have the same fid. That is probably the cause.

Comment: @IanTurton The Polygons are not the same no.